# Hook jQuery script into both <input> and <button> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I am using following Javascript code to handle all forms in ajax:

```
$(':submit:not(.form-default-submit)').click(function(event) {
    //Disable normal form submission, handle using ajax
});
```

This hooks into all tags like

```
<input type="submit">
```

that don't have the class `form-default-submit`

Unfortunatelly I've just noticed that this doesn't pick up on the `button` tag, for example:

```
<button type="submit"></button>
```

which I would like to happen.

Is it possible to modify this Javascript to hook into both elements from the one function? Or would I have to use two separate `.click` events for each element?

Comment: By using a `,`, you can combine multiple selectors into one, just like in css.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[`,`](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)** for separating **[multiple selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)**

```
$(':submit,button[type="submit"]').not('.form-default-submit').click(function(event) {
    //Disable normal form submission, handle using ajax
});
```

or you can use **[attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)**

```
$('[type="submit"]:not(.form-default-submit)').click(function(event) {
    //Disable normal form submission, handle using ajax
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use comma to separate:

```
$(':submit:not(.form-default-submit), button[type=submit]:not(.form-default-submit)').click(function(event) {
    //x
});
```

**Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/0c1q9aqd/**

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$(':submit:not(.form-default-submit), input[type=submit]').click(function(event) {
    //Disable normal form submission, handle using ajax
});
```